# Unlocking Wizard Dialogue Options 2 and 3

Tags: soda-dungeon

In Soda Dungeon I reached Dimension 10 and I am about level 1370, but I still can't see the last two dialogue options for the wizard.
The first one is  "Warp," but the others only show "????."

How do I unlock them?
Do I need to buy "CUSTOM" and "M.CLOCK?"

Answer (score 1):

I'm still trying to figure out how to unlock option 3 but #2 you have to gain 1.5 billion coin. Save up and it will unlock.

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 was meant to be in a future update for enchanting. It doesn’t exist and most likely won’t until SD2. Hope this helped.